# truncating file in 'r+' makes the entire file rectangles

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

The following is my code:

```
import json
id = "iderq23512345123521"
with open("file.json", "r+") as f:

        data = json.loads(f.read())
        f.truncate(0)
        del data[id]
        data = json.dumps(data)
        f.write(subs)
```

[This is what the file looks like after I do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqbIj.png)

When I try to copy and paste the characters, they don't show up

Comment: try with `del data["id"]` -- notice the quotes. `id` is a builtin python function

Comment: id was a variable. I forgot to include the prior code. Just edited it.

Comment: Have you checked the binary contents of the file with something like `hexdump`? The "rectangles" might indicate a text encoding problem: Python could be saving the file in one encoding, and whatever program you're using to open the file could be opening it in another encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `id` variable to something else (like `id2`), `id` already is a python func